# How to download a file using winsock or wininet

Tags: c, download, winsock, wininet

I could not find any code samples using Google. Could someone please show me how to do it? I think we need to use winsock or wininet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't search that much...

recv function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Also, you'll also need to look at using HTTP GETs (if you're using HTTP).